# Embedding jzy3d in applet

Tags: java, applet, awt, jzy3d

I am trying to create an applet that creates a graph, but the applet opens another window.
I don't know what changes should be done in code in order to make it work.
I understand that the reason for it is `ChartLauncher`.

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.media.opengl.GLAnimatorControl;
import javax.media.opengl.GLAutoDrawable;
import javax.media.opengl.GLEventListener;
import javax.media.opengl.GLProfile;
import javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;

import org.jzy3d.chart.Chart;
import org.jzy3d.chart.ChartLauncher;
import org.jzy3d.colors.Color;
import org.jzy3d.maths.Coord3d;
import org.jzy3d.plot3d.primitives.Point;
import org.jzy3d.plot3d.primitives.Polygon;
import org.jzy3d.plot3d.primitives.Shape;

import com.jogamp.opengl.util.FPSAnimator;


public class AppletPolygons  extends Applet{
private GLAnimatorControl glanimatorcontrol;

public void init() {
    GLProfile.initSingleton();
    setLayout( new BorderLayout() );        

    final GLCanvas glcanvas = new GLCanvas();
    glcanvas.addGLEventListener( new GLEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3, int arg4) {

        }

        @Override
        public void init( GLAutoDrawable glautodrawable ) {
            // Build a polygon list
            double [][]distDataProp = new double[][] {{5,10, .20},{10, 20, .45}, {30, 40,.7}};
            List<Polygon> polygons = new ArrayList<Polygon>();
            for(int i = 0; i < distDataProp.length -1; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < distDataProp[i].length -1; j++){
                    Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
                    polygon.add(new Point( new Coord3d(i, j, distDataProp[i][j]) ));
                    polygon.add(new Point( new Coord3d(i, j+1, distDataProp[i][j+1]) ));
                    polygon.add(new Point( new Coord3d(i+1, j+1, distDataProp[i+1][j+1]) ));
                    polygon.add(new Point( new Coord3d(i+1, j, distDataProp[i+1][j]) ));

                    if ((j % 2) == 0)
                        polygon.setColor(Color.RED);
                    else
                        polygon.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                    polygons.add(polygon);
                }
            }

            Point p = new Point();
            Coord3d n = new Coord3d();
            n.x=100;
            n.y=5;
            n.z=2;
            p.setData(n);
            p.setWidth(10);
            p.setColor(Color.BLACK);

            Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
            polygon.add(new Point( new Coord3d(1, 2, -1*distDataProp[0][0]) ));
            polygon.add(new Point( new Coord3d(1, 3, -1*distDataProp[0][1]) ));
            polygon.add(new Point( new Coord3d(2, 3, -1*distDataProp[1][1]) ));
            polygon.add(new Point( new Coord3d(2, 2, -1*distDataProp[1][0]) ));

            polygon.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);

            polygons.add(polygon);

            // Creates the 3d object
            Shape surface = new Shape(polygons);
            surface.add(p);
            surface.setWireframeDisplayed(true);
            surface.setWireframeColor(org.jzy3d.colors.Color.BLACK);

            Chart chart = new Chart();

            chart.getScene().getGraph().add(surface);

            chart.getAxeLayout().setXTickColor(Color.CYAN);
            chart.getAxeLayout().setYTickColor(Color.BLUE);
            chart.getAxeLayout().setZTickColor(Color.BLUE);

            ChartLauncher.openChart(chart, "my garph");         

        }

        @Override
        public void dispose( GLAutoDrawable glautodrawable ) {
        }

        @Override
        public void display( GLAutoDrawable glautodrawable ) {

            }

    });

    glcanvas.setSize( getSize() );
    add( glcanvas, BorderLayout.CENTER );
    glanimatorcontrol = new FPSAnimator( glcanvas, 30 );
}

public void start() {
    glanimatorcontrol.start();
}

public void stop() {
    glanimatorcontrol.stop();
}

public void destroy() {
}
}
```

Comment: `import org.jzy3d.chart.ChartLauncher;` Hmm.. given the poor [documentation](http://jzy3d.org/documentation/javadoc/0.9/org/jzy3d/chart/ChartLauncher.html) I'd recommend finding a better (documented) API.

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) For deploying Java desktop apps., the best option is usually to install the app. using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS works on Windows, OS X & *nix.

Comment: ChartLauncher is a helper class to display a chart in a frame. Method names appeared to me quite explicit. If some of them do not appear clear to you, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The developer guide provides an applet example (http://www.jzy3d.org/guide.php).

Note that applets do not easily run on ALL platforms. I was able to have an applet running properly on Windows and Ubuntu, but I got stuck when trying to run it on MacOS+Chrome.

You might wish to try a running example before buying the guide : http://www.jzy3d.org/release/0.9/applet/jzy3d-applet.html

If you would like to go for a JNLP, then you should look at this page (http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Using_JOGL_in_Java_Web_Start) explaining how to package a JOGL based JNLP application.